# flask_socketio irregular generated event on VPS

Tags: flask-socketio

Goodmorning,

I have implemented this example:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example

and I look:

1. works well locally
2. when copy the files in a VPS, I obtain this trend with irregular time delay. Sometimes it is block and then after 70 or 80 seconds restart for 5 events and then it is block and then restart.

Why? What am I doing wrong? I use gunicorn.

Received #0: Connected
Received #1: I'm connected!
Received #1: Server generated event
Received #2: Server generated event
Received #3: Server generated event
Received #4: Server generated event
Received #5: Server generated event
Received #6: Server generated event
Received #7: Server generated event
Received #8: Server generated event
Received #9: Server generated event
Received #10: Server generated event
Received #11: Server generated event
Received #12: Server generated event
Received #13: Server generated event
Received #14: Server generated event
Received #15: Server generated event
Received #16: Server generated event
Received #0: Connected
Received #1: I'm connected!
Received #22: Server generated event
Received #23: Server generated event
Received #24: Server generated event
Received #25: Server generated event
Received #26: Server generated event
Received #0: Connected
Received #1: I'm connected!
Received #1: Server generated event
Received #2: Server generated event
Received #3: Server generated event
Received #4: Server generated event
Received #5: Server generated event
Received #6: Server generated event
Received #7: Server generated event
Received #8: Server generated event
Received #9: Server generated event
Received #10: Server generated event
Received #11: Server generated event
Received #12: Server generated event
Received #13: Server generated event
Received #14: Server generated event
Received #15: Server generated event
Received #16: Server generated event
Received #17: Server generated event
Received #0: Connected
Received #1: I'm connected!
Received #1: Server generated event
Received #2: Server generated event
Received #3: Server generated event
Received #4: Server generated event
Received #5: Server generated event
Received #6: Server generated event
Received #0: Connected
Received #1: I'm connected!
Received #1: Server generated event
Received #2: Server generated event
Received #3: Server generated event
Received #4: Server generated event
Received #5: Server generated event
Received #0: Connected
Received #1: I'm connected!
Received #5: Server generated event
Received #6: Server generated event

Comment: You need to add the command that you use to start your application (both locally and in your VPS) and the complete list of requirements in both installations.

Comment: LOCALLY, 
In my LAN, I use VS.Code, and from new terminal the command is: 
flask run --host=192.168.0.67 

requirements.txt
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-SocketIO==4.3.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
python-dotenv==0.13.0
python-engineio==3.12.1
python-socketio==4.5.1
six==1.15.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1

VPS:
from flask.conf
command=/home/user/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 run:app

requirements.txt
like the previous one

Comment: Check the Flask-SocketIO documentation to learn how to start Gunicorn for Socket.IO usage. The `-w 4` is wrong, you have to use 1 worker. You are also missing the `-k` option.